4/4 time change to 6/8 time
I have a classical piece that changes from 4/4 time to 6/8 time and indicates a quarter note in 4/4 time = a dotted quarter in 6/8 time.
I have no idea what this means.

Presumably it means that from that point on, the time is 6/8 in such a tempo that 3/8 out of those 6/8 are just as long as 1/4 was in the part that was in 4/4.

Do you know what meters mean in music?  That may be the source of your confusion


I have a classical piece that changes from 4/4 time to 6/8 time and indicates a quarter note in 4/4 time = a dotted quarter in 6/8 time.

If you think of 6/8 as being similar to triplets in 2/4 it should be easy to understand. Here is an image that compares those options:


When in 4/4 time, the tempo is measured in quarter notes. 100 BPM (beats per minute) means 100 quarter notes per minute.
In 6/8 time, the beat is (usually) measured in dotted quarter notes, with two beats per measure. So 100 BPM means 100 dotted quarter notes per minute.
The marking (quarter note = dotted quarter note) means that the BPM (i.e., quarter note speed) of the 4/4 portion of the music transitions to the dotted quarter note in 6/8 time. Thus, if the 4/4 part was 100 BPM, now the 6/8 part will also be 100 BPM. All that's changing is the type of note that represents one beat.

A possibly useful additional way of thinking about what's going on in what you describe is that the pulse stays identically the same but the subdivision of each beat changes from simple/duple to compund/triple (i.e. this is one way of thinking of what it means for the type of note to change)

BPM means beats per minute, and in 4/4, at, say, 60bpm, there will be one beat (one crotchet/1/4 note) per second. In the case where 4/4 changes to 6/8, with a crotchet changing (at 60bpm) to a dotted crotchet at that same 60bpm, then tapping one's foot 4 times at one second intervals in the first will stay at the same tapping speed, but there will be only two taps per bar.
Rather like each bar in 6/8 is half as long as those bars in 4/4, and, in addition, the feel will be two sets of triplets to each tap of the foot.
